# How to verify the @jit() decorator works on GPU?

Tags: python, gpu, numba

while working on my code, I couldn't find any acceleration after using @jit decorator even with the nopython=True option.

I have doubts that jit really supports GPU cause I didn't find this option in its arguments. I also think parallel=True option is for the CPU cores.

Any hits, corrections?
How can I verify that my code works on the GPU?

Many thanks :)

Comment: what makes you think the `@jit` decorator works on the GPU?  The decorators I'm aware of that can make use of the gpu are `@cuda.jit` , `@vectorize` , `@guvectorize` , `@cuda.reduce`   see [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Robert. So what is the benefit of using @jit ?

Comment: It combines both: 1. a parallelization strategy (i.e. a way to expose parallelism to the machine)  2. The benefits of JIT compilation in a python environment.  These benefits can provide significant performance improvement even in a CPU-only environment.